# My application crashes while saving an image to ms access second time using c#

Tags: winforms, c#-2.0

I use ms access 2007 and c#2.0 winforms. I successfully saved an image to the first customer  and retrieved it.When i try to save an image for the second customer , my application gets crashed,i think image is saving correctly only for the first time when i run my application.

Here is my code

```
      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

            conn.Open();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            FileStream imgf = null;
            StreamReader imgr = null;
            imgf = new FileStream(pictureBox1.ImageLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            imgr = new StreamReader(imgf);
            byte[] pray = new byte[imgf.Length];
            imgf.Read(pray, 0, Convert.ToInt32(imgf.Length));
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into member (fname,lname,mobile,dob,address,city,state,pcode,email,lastcheck,doj,memstat,flag,checkdate,picimg) values('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "','" + richTextBox1.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + comboBox1.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "','" + today + "','" + today + "',False,'" + a + "','" + today + "',@photo)";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@photo", OleDbType.Binary, Convert.ToInt32(imgf.Length)).Value = pray;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
      }
```

Please help me..

Comment: My application crashes while trying to do save operation for the second time..

Comment: I did its about SQL injunction and its effects.

Comment: i used strings @parameters to insert the data still my application crashes. I get an error"vshost.exe has stopped working"